How to install ros on jetson orin
I have nvidia jetson orin having following ubuntu install
nvidia@ubuntu:~lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: 20.04.06 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal 

when I try to install ros noetic sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full got followiong error
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

to solve the above problem I tried these Ask Ubuntu and Stackoverflow but nothing work

I was constantly getting errors while installing with Nvidia SDK. Then I installed the system with this video. (Do not install via virtual machine)
After the installation, I continued by following the Noetic installations from the website and it was completed successfully.

Make sure your package lists are up-to-date:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Try to fix any broken dependencies:
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Held packages might be causing the problem. You can check for held packages with the following command:
sudo apt-mark showhold

If any packages are listed, you can try unholding them with:
sudo apt-mark unhold <package_name>

Clean up your package manager by removing any unnecessary packages and clearing the cache:
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean

After performing the steps above, try installing ROS Noetic again:
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full


I tried it but still the problem is same, I am using jatpack of cuda etc is this causing the problem?

It shouldn't, when did you install Ubuntu on your Jetson?

Last week using Nvidia SDK

If the problem doesn't go away, maybe you need to reinstall Ubuntu. Maybe something went wrong during the installation or maybe you changed something which you don't remember.
